# Rx with button tap and hold event in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, system.reactive

I have a simple Windows Phone 8 app with a button and a textbox. How do I use Reactive Extensions for the button Tap and Hold event to change the TextBox text?

```
void AttachRx()
    {
IScheduler cs = new DispatcherScheduler(Deployment.Current.Dispatcher);

        Observable.FromEvent<System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs>(btn, "Tap").Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(.5), cs)
            .Do(a => ChangeText()).Subscribe();
    }
```

error message:

> {System.InvalidOperationException: The event delegate must be of the form void Handler(object, T) where T : EventArgs.
>      at Microsoft.Phone.Reactive.Observable.FromEvent[TEventArgs](Object target, String eventName)
>      at PhoneApp4.MainPage.AttachRx()
>      at PhoneApp4.MainPage..ctor()}

Comment: Presumably, you aren't audaciously asking for a complete Rx tutorial here. Your question is too vague. There are a variety of tap and hold events and different states reported in those events on WP8. Please provide a detailed description of the event sequence you want to respond to and the response you want to make. Without a serious effort to provide more detail, this question should be closed.

Comment: added code sample. the problem is that on KeyUp event there are no errors thrown. But when the button is clicked the ChangeText method doesn't fire. But when event is cnaged from KeyUp to Tap/Hold error is thrown

Comment: OK, good changes. Close vote retracted and answered now!

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues to address here.

The error you've reported is specifically saying that the delegate you are trying to add to the Tap event is not compatible - which makes sense because I don't imagine the `Tap` event has a `KeyEventArgs` payload (I think it is `GestureEventArgs`)? You are also probably better off using `Observable.FromEventPattern` as used in my example below. It's easier as you can get away with inferring the `EventArgs` type.

*Caveat* - As I have only WP8.1 SDK on my laptop at the moment, I have only the Win RT `Tapped` Event which is different from `Tap`, so I've just read the docs on `Tap` and not run the example below.

Assuming a `Button` called `btn` and a `TextBox` called txt and a function `string GetText()` that gets the text to set, do this:

```
Observable.FromEventPattern<GestureEventArgs>(btn, "Tap")
    .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5))
    .Select(_ => GetText())
    .ObserveOnDispatcher()
    .Subscribe(x => this.txt.Text = x);
```

Note a few things here:

- Use `FromEventPattern` when standard .NET events are available - it better suited for this than `FromEvent` which really exists to handle non-conforming delegates.
- Don't use `Do` like this. It works as a side-effect and isn't really idiomatic functional reactive programming. Doing this is in general could also cause unintended problems in more complex queries. Instead, project the input event to the desired result with a `Select`.
- Don't run the `Throttle` on the dispatcher - use the default scheduler (or parameterize for testability with `.Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5), Scheduler.Default)`. You don't need the Throttle to run on the dispatcher - it's better off in the background. You only want to transfer to the dispatcher when you are ready to update the UI.
- If you import nuget package `rx-xaml` you can use `ObservableOnDispatcher` to grab the current dispatcher. Although, for testability, you may wish to use the overload of `ObserveOn` (also in rx-xaml) that takes a dependency object like the page you are running on - e.g. `ObserveOn(this)` if you set up the subscription in the page code-behind for example, the page itself will do.

The example above assumes that `GetText` is synchronous. If you need to make an *asynchronous* call to get the text you wish to display, use the following pattern (assuming that `GetText` has a `Task<String>` return type):

```
Observable.FromEventPattern<GestureEventArgs>(btn, "Tap")
          .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5), Scheduler.Default)
          .Select(_ => Observable.FromAsync(GetText)
                                 .ObserveOn(this))
          .Switch()
          .Subscribe(x => this.Name.Text = x);
```

Note the strange looking placement of `ObserveOn` inside the `Select`. The reasons for this are quite complex to explain briefly (and I'm not sure how relevant it is to this question), but basically it avoids a race condition where if a long running async GetText call for an earlier event could over-write the results of a short running call due to a later event.